# Notify when download finish dropbox Core API

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm making a module that can download all file from apps folder on dropbox to devices.

Now, I'm using Core API to download a file. Everything works fine. But with multiple file, I don't know when the current file finish download to go to the next file.

Here is my download code:

```
final String cachePath = FileHandler.ROOT_LOCAL_FOLDER_DIR + "/" + mFile.getFileName();
            try {
                mFos = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                mErrorMsg = "Couldn't create a local file to store the image";
                return false;
            }

            ProgressListener mProgressLisenter = new ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long arg0, long arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tmpFile = new File(cachePath);
                    OnDownloadProgressDropboxChecked(FileHandler.PROGRESS_STATUS_ONPROGRESS, (int) (arg0 * 100 / arg1));
                }

                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    return 100;
                }
            };
            mDownloaded = mApi.getFile(mFile.getFileId(), null, mFos, mProgressLisenter);
                    OnDownloadDropboxChecked(TRUE, "Download complete");
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            mErrorMsg = "Unlinked";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Download canceled";

        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
        }
}
```

I've tried:

- Catch progress download, when reached 100% then notify - On this way, the OnProgress of dropbox isn't show up imediately and sometime It not reach 100%
- Put It in a asynctask - Useless

I'm out of idea now, any advance are good for me.

---

Edited:
the solution is put some trigger under getFile() then It work.

here is my complete class:

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> implements DConst {

    Context act;
    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    // private String mPath;

    private FileOutputStream mFos;

    private boolean mCanceled;
    private Long mFileLen;
    private String mErrorMsg;
    private String mFileName;
    String path;
    DFile mFile;
    DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo mDownloaded;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public DownloadFile(Context act, DropboxAPI<?> api, DFile mDFile) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        this.act = act;
        mApi = api;
        mFile = mDFile;
        path = mDFile.getFileId();
        mFileName = mDFile.getFileName();
        OnDownloadProgressDropboxChecked(FileHandler.PROGRESS_STATUS_START, 0);
    }

    File tmpFile;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            final String cachePath = FileHandler.ROOT_LOCAL_FOLDER_DIR + "/" + mFile.getFileName();
            try {
                mFos = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                mErrorMsg = "Couldn't create a local file to store the image";
                return false;
            }

            ProgressListener mProgressLisenter = new ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long arg0, long arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tmpFile = new File(cachePath);
                    OnDownloadProgressDropboxChecked(FileHandler.PROGRESS_STATUS_ONPROGRESS, (int) (arg0 * 100 / arg1));
                    Log.d("Dolphin got interval", String.valueOf(tmpFile.length() + " - " + arg0 + " - " + arg1));
                }

                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    return 100;
                }
            };
            mDownloaded = mApi.getFile(mFile.getFileId(), null, mFos, mProgressLisenter);

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            mErrorMsg = "Unlinked";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Download canceled";

        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception. These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._304_NOT_MODIFIED) {
                // won't happen since we don't pass in revision with metadata
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them. You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE) {
                // too many entries to return
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._415_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA) {
                // can't be thumbnailed
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } finally {
            if (mFos != null) {
                try {
                    mFos.close();
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        OnDownloadProgressDropboxChecked(FileHandler.PROGRESS_STATUS_FINISH, 0);
        if (result) {
            OnDownloadDropboxChecked(TRUE, "Download complete");
        } else {
            OnDownloadDropboxChecked(FALSE, mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    OnAsyncDownloadListener onAsyncDownloadListener;
    OnAsyncDownloadProgressListener onAsyncDownloadProgressListener;

    private void OnDownloadDropboxChecked(int res, String messenger) {
        if (onAsyncDownloadListener != null) {
            onAsyncDownloadListener.OnAsyncDownload(res, messenger);
        }
    }

    private void OnDownloadProgressDropboxChecked(int status, int percent) {
        if (onAsyncDownloadProgressListener != null) {
            onAsyncDownloadProgressListener.OnAsyncDownloadProgress(status, percent);
        }
    }

    public void setOnAsyncDownloadListener(OnAsyncDownloadListener listener) {
        onAsyncDownloadListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnAsyncDownloadProgressListener(OnAsyncDownloadProgressListener listener) {
        onAsyncDownloadProgressListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnAsyncDownloadListener {
        public abstract void OnAsyncDownload(int res, String messenger);
    }

    public interface OnAsyncDownloadProgressListener {
        public abstract void OnAsyncDownloadProgress(int status, int percent);
    }
}
```

The error caused by 'OnDownloadDropboxChecked()' of Asynctask fired before the one of getFile(). So It return a false notify.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're using the Android Core API SDK, right? If so, I think that when mApi.getFile returns, the file has been downloaded. So can't you do whatever you need to do on the next line?

Comment: @smart sorry for late reply. Do  you mean under 'mDownloaded = mApi.getFile(mFile.getFileId(), null, mFos, mProgressLisenter);' ? I've tried but the result are the same

Comment: What do you mean by "the results are the same?" What results?

Comment: @smarx I've checked my code many times and found the problem. 
You are right. It return an object and when finish, It run to the next line. You can post an answer for upvote. 
A big thank for great answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

If I'm reading this right, you're using the Android Core API SDK, right? If so, I think that when mApi.getFile returns, the file has been downloaded. So you can do whatever you need to do on the next line.